# Allow control allow origin add-on for chrome install offline

Tags: google-chrome-extension, add-on, crx

My work place does not have internet connection and I want a Chrome add-on named "Allow control allow origin". I read there is a CRX file which can be used to install add-on offline. So what I planned is I will download the CRX file at home and mail it at my work email ID and install it from there. But I am not able to find the CRX file download link. Can anyone help me with a proper download link for CRX file? OR is there any other way I can use this add-on offline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this https://chrome-extension-downloader.com/ and paste the extension link and it will give you the crx file.

Anyway, here's the crx file http://www.mediafire.com/file/zb2eqja84a9fgvv/Allow-Control-Allow-Origin_-__v1.0.3.crx

Answer (score 1):

You can download and install it offline.

Here you go:

https://chrome-extension-downloader.com/65e059c1417494a49674ee9e0e541f73/https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en.crx

Generated by https://chrome-extension-downloader.com/